# Clojure: How do I factor proxy method code out of a long proxy statement?

Tags: clojure, proxy, refactoring

I have a Clojure `proxy` statement that was getting large and messy, so I decided to try factoring the code of the `beginDrag` method redefinition out of the `proxy` statement, like this:

```
(defn enhanced-start-drag
  ""
  [pie]
  (let [pobj   (. pie getPickedNode)
    pobj-coll (seq (.. pie getInputManager
               getKeyboardFocus getSelection))]
    (println pobj)
    (println pobj-coll)
    (println "----------")
    (proxy-super startDrag pie)))  ; THIS IS LINE 94 (SEE ERROR MSG)



(defn custom-selection-event-handler [marqueeParent selectableParent]
  (proxy [PSelectionEventHandler]  [marqueeParent selectableParent]
    (decorateSelectedNode [node]
              (let [stroke-color (Color/red)]
                (.setStrokePaint node stroke-color)))
    (undecorateSelectedNode [node]
                (let [stroke-color (Color/black)]
                  (.setStrokePaint node stroke-color)))
    (startDrag [pie]    ; pie is a PInputEvent
           (enhanced-start-drag pie))
    (endStandardSelection [pie]     ; pie is a PInputEvent
              (let [pobj   (.getPickedNode pie)
                slip   (. pobj getAttribute "slip")
                ]
                (swap! *last-slip-clicked*
                   (fn [x] slip))))))
```

I get the following compile error:

```
cd /Users/gw/tech/clojurestuff/cljprojects/infwb/src/infwb/
1 compiler notes:

Unknown location:
  error: java.lang.Exception: Unable to resolve symbol: this in this context

core.clj:94:5:
  error: java.lang.Exception: Unable to resolve symbol: this in this context 
    (core.clj:94)

Compilation failed.
```

As soon as I restore the body of `enhanced-start-drag` into the body of the `proxy` statement, everything works.

**My question:** Is there a way to move the messy details out to a separate function to improve the readability of my code?

Thanks for all your ideas and solutions.

---

**UPDATE, 10/27/11:** See the comments below. Arthur Ulfeldt was sharp in pointing out that the issue is captured references, and Dave Ray is also correct in saying that all you have to do is add `this` as a parameter to `enhanced-start-drag` and then `proxy-super` will work correctly.  When I made the following two changes (without any changes to the *body* of `enhanced-start-drag`), my code was working again:

```
  (defn enhanced-start-drag
    ""
    [pie this]
```

and

```
  (startDrag [pie]  ; IN THE PROXY STMT IN custom-selection-event-handler
   (enhanced-start-drag pie this))
```

BTW, my project uses Dave Ray's `seesaw` project to get a Java Swing UI. `seesaw` is awesome, as are its docstrings and sample code (which are much better than most commercial software). I highly recommend it! And thank you, Dave!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have been bitten by **[symbol capture](http://www.enrico-franchi.org/2011/03/wanted-and-unwanted-symbol-capture.html)**. In this case it is intentaional though you need to stay aware of it. From the doc for `proxy-super`

```
Use to call a superclass method in the body of a proxy method. 
Note, expansion captures 'this`
```

proxy is creating a class that calls a function, when the call gets into `enhanced-start-drag` the value of `this` is not where proxy-super expects

you may needs to pass `this` as another argument into enhanced-start-drag and then call `(. saved-this  ...)` instead of using proxy-super.

---

Comment: Passing `this` won't work because then calling `.startDrag` will create an infinite loop. Another solution might be to make `enhanced-start-drag` into a macro.

Comment: Including `this` as a parameter to `enhanced-start-drag` and then calling `proxy-super` will work fine. No infinite loops. Here's an example: https://github.com/daveray/seesaw/blob/develop/src/seesaw/core.clj#L2431